# Doubly periodic function is not a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f$ is a doubly periodic function (with periods linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$) then $f$ cannot be a rational function.
I am not sure how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Look at the poles of $f$.

Comment: Wouldn't any rational function be non-periodic due to any asymptotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a complex plane, non-constant doubly periodic function have infinite number of poles, however, the number of poles of rational depends on its degree so its finite.